# edismax doesn't support CommonGramsQueryFilterFactory?

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR 3.6 for search server and have a `text_general` type which is:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" /> 
    <filter class="solr.StemmerOverrideFilterFactory" dictionary="stemdict.txt" /> 
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsQueryFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" /> 
    <filter class="solr.StemmerOverrideFilterFactory" dictionary="stemdict.txt" /> 
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But I found when I use `edismax` for searching "to be or not to be", the whole phrase would be removed due to the stopwords configuration. But I did use `CommonGramsQueryFilterFactory` for query analysing. The debug shows:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">to be or not to be</str>
<str name="querystring">to be or not to be</str>
<str name="parsedquery">+()</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">+()</str>
```

Where did I do wrong? edismax doesn't support CommonGramsQueryFilterFactory?

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory says

> "Makes shingles (i.e. the_cat) by combining common tokens (usually the same as the stop words list) and regular tokens."

Looks like it only combines common tokens with regular tokens. What you are trying to do is combine common tokens with common tokens which may be the reason to fail.

I haven't tried it but was looking at using it and bumped into your question and this piece of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that edismax tokenizes the query and analyzes each term by it own.
The CommonGramsQueryFilter should get all the words in order to produce the pairs, but in this case it gets the term 'to' and does nothing, then the term 'be' and does nothing and so on..

So in that case, the CommonGramsQueryFilter does nothing and the StopFilterFactory removes all the stop words and leaves you with an empty query.